# Java Generics Class Type Conformance

Tags: java, generics, types

So I had a Java method like this...

```
public int foo(Class<? extends bar> someClass){....}
```

So code works with the subtypes that extends bar.
I want to see what happens when I pass in Customer.class (not compile)
and String.class (not compile), as expected.
Then I want to try bar class itself. The compiler did not complain.
So I know a class can't really extend itself. However a class's type does conform
to itself. So maybe this is how Java implements this "bounded type parameter".

So what is happening?

Comment: `extends` in a type parameter bound doesn't mean the same thing as the `extends` in an inheritance clause. You being able to pass `bar.class` in there doesn't really imply that a class can extend itself. `? extends bar` just means "the least derived type that this type can be is `bar`".

Comment: They probably didn't want to throw in a new keyword. So they reused `extends`.

Comment: By the way, you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase; class names in PascalCase. `bar` should be `Bar`.